# Python - ezsheets error: KeyError: Status

Tags: python

I tried following the steps in

https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter14/

and tried to get the spreadsheet title from a sheet I just created but got the following error.

How can I fix this, can someone please help?

[image: Screenshot VSCODE]

Comment: There is another error above saying access to the specific google sheet is blocked or not configured. I would check for any possible permission issue. Have you done all the necessary steps like enabling the API and getting the credentials for authentication (the credentials-sheets.json file) ? Maybe this link can help https://statisticallyrelevant.com/how-to-analyse-google-sheets-data-in-python-using-ezsheets/

Comment: Solved now, Thanks Bao Huynh Lam

Comment: Nice! Glad to know it is solved. Would you write your answer down below so others who encounter similar problems can be helped ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that I enabled a different API that he app to be enabled. Usually if you encounter this error. Just press the link provided in the error below and follow the steps outlined by Google. This would work fine :)